# Placing quotes in JS parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically populating an unordered list with JS for my mobile app. I am using JQuery mobile and Phonegap for developing.

In my list I want to call a function with parameters when clicked. I am able to call the function `downloadPdf()` without using any parameters, but not if I add them. I think it has something to do with quotes/double qoutes.

```
var $li = $("<li><a href='#' onclick='downloadPdf('"+val.title+"', '"+val.url+"')'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
```

I am not able to debug as I am running this on my phone, so I hope someone with a more trained eye is able to see what's wrong here. Both `val.title` and `val.url` holds values of string type.

Comment: Don't use `onclick`, use a proper click handler and make this a lot easier on yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use inline events. You are using jQuery, it makes it easy to attach events

```
var li = $("<li><a href='#'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
li.find("a").on("click", function(){ downloadPdf(val.title,val.url); });
```

---

or use Data Attributes and a generic onclick handler

```
var li = $("<li><a class='download' href='#'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
li.find("a").data("title", val.title).data("url", val.url);
```

and the generic click

```
$(document).on("click", "a.download", function (event) {
   var anc = $(this);
   downloadPdf( anc.data("title"), anc.data("url"));
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You should be using `.text()` on the anchor tag.  Otherwise, you're not escaping the title, opening yourself up to invalid HTML and injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes

```js
var val = {title: 'foo', url: 'http://foo'}

var $li = $('<li><a href="#" onclick="downloadPdf(\'' + val.title + '\',\'' +  val.url + '\')">' + val.title + '</a></li>');
  
function downloadPdf() {
 alert('params:' + JSON.stringify(arguments, null, 2));
}

$('body').append($li);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or for better practice use click event handlers as @epascarello suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello is right, do not use inline event handlers.

But answering directly on the question just escape double quotes:

```
$("<li><a href='#' onclick='downloadPdf(\""+val.title+"\", \""+val.url+"\")'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
```

Produces:

```
<li><a href='#' onclick='downloadPdf("value1", "value2")'>title</a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

First I advice putting the code in multiple lines just to ease reading.

```
var $li = $(''
+ '<li>'
    + '<a href="#" onclick="downloadPdf(\"' + val.title + '\", \"' + val.url + '\")">' + val.title 
    + '</a>'
+ '</li>');
```

I specially do this for this awful templates.

Second you need to escape the quotes using `\"` or `\'`

---

### Real advice

pay some attention to what epascarello is saying there. His way is way better and easy to understand, than the escaping mess in a single line.

Comment: That won't work. The escape (which is meaningless in HTML anyway) is going to be consumed by the JS parser so the parsed string is going to include `onclick="downloadPdf("` which is wrong.